# clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" wrong units in Chrome in SVG

Tags: svg, clip-path

I am dealing with Chrome counting weirdly with units in SVG when using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

Here's the narrowest version I could come up with which works correctly in Firefox:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #inhibitor-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="figure-crop" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5"></circle>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(500, 500)">
      <circle r="500" fill="red"></circle>
      <foreignObject x="-500" y="-500" width="1000" height="1000" clip-path="url(#figure-crop)">
        <img id="inhibitor-image" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to figure out that If I switch circle positioning to `cx="1"` and `cy="1"` then it works in Chrome but not in Firefox, here is snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #inhibitor-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="figure-crop" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="0.5"></circle>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(500, 500)">
      <circle r="500" fill="red"></circle>
      <foreignObject x="-500" y="-500" width="1000" height="1000" clip-path="url(#figure-crop)">
        <img id="inhibitor-image" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what is going on and I don't want to implement JS switch for different browsers.

Comment: Report the problem to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Ok, posted: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1009222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of foreignObject and the transform seems to be the problem. When you move the transform effect directly into element positioning, the problem seems to go away. My guess is that Chrome is not capturing the transform applied by the image CSS and is mis-calculating the objectBoundingBox.

This code works the same in both Firefox and Chrome. (foreignObject has lots of bugs IMHO, so try to avoid it as much as possible. Maybe just use an SVG image element and script based positioning.)

```html
<head> 
<style>
    #inhibitor-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="figure-crop" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5"></circle>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>

      <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="500" fill="red"></circle>
      <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" clip-path="url(#figure-crop)">
        <img id="inhibitor-image" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      </foreignObject>
  </svg>
```

**EDIT**
Another possibility is to wrap foreignObject into nested group and translate using the group's transform:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #inhibitor-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="figure-crop" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5"></circle>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(500, 500)">
      <circle r="500" fill="red"></circle>
      <g transform="translate(-500, -500)">
        <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" clip-path="url(#figure-crop)">
          <img id="inhibitor-image" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will review it on PC. However, even though not mentioned in the question, I use panzoom library and it wraps everything into a group and applies transform to move the SVG on the screen. So I guess, I'm screwed up.

Comment: You led me in the right direction. For reasons out of scope of this answer I cannot remove the outer group. However you can `<foreignObject>` x and y to 0, then wrap it in nested group and give the group `transform="translate(-500, -500)"`. This works in both Chrome and Firefox. I will edit your answer so that it's clear this is also a solution. After you review it, I will accept your answer.